# getting fs.readme to work with async await and promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to create a node script that looks into my inbox of recently created markdown notes, finds the metadata at the top of that note, finds the category within that metadata and then moves the file into its relevant folder. I keep getting the error message:

```
(node:82025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: paths is not defined
```

I believe this is because my code is not waiting for the readFile function to finish, despite me having labeled it as async/await and having wrapped it in promisify at the top of the file. Could someone please point me in the direction as to where I'm going wrong? Complete code below (other dependencies are for another script):

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const firstline = require('firstline');
    const moment = require('moment');
    const { promisify } = require('util');
    
    const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
    
    const pathToResources =
      '/Users/Rob/Library/Mobile Documents/9CR7T2DMDG~com~ngocluu~onewriter/Documents/Test/Resources/';
    
    function markdownNotesOnly(files) {
      return (notes = files.filter((file) => path.extname(file) === '.md'));
    }
    
    async function getNewPath(note) {
      let oldPath = path.join(__dirname, note);
      let paths = {};
      let newPath = '';
    
      readFile(oldPath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        let metadata = data
          .toString()
          .match(/-{3}\n.*\n-{3}/gms)
          .toString();
        let category = metadata.match(/#§-\d{3}-.*/);
    
        if (!category) {
          paths = { oldPath, newPath };
          return paths;
        }
    
        category = category.toString().substring(3);
        newPath = path.join(pathToResources, category);
        paths = { oldPath, newPath };
        return paths;
      });
    }
    
    function sortFiles(startPath) {
      fs.readdir(startPath, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        markdownNotesOnly(files); // returns array called notes
    
        notes.map(async (note) => {
          await getNewPath(note);
    
          let { oldPath, newPath } = paths;
    
          fs.rename(oldPath, path.join(newPath, note), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('File moved successfully');
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

Update:
Followed the advice of Mestre San below and got it working this morning. Here is my finished code if it is of use to anybody.

```js
import { readdir, rename } from 'fs';
import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
import { resolve, extname, join } from 'path';
const __dirname = resolve();

const pathToResources =
  '/Users/Rob/Library/Mobile Documents/9CR7T2DMDG~com~ngocluu~onewriter/Documents/Test/Resources/';

function markdownNotesOnly(files) {
  let notes = files.filter((file) => extname(file) === '.md');
  return notes;
}

async function getPaths(note) {
  const metadataRegex = /-{3}\n.*\n-{3}/gms;
  const categoryRegex = /#§-\d{3}-.*/;
  let oldPath = join(__dirname, note);
  let newPath = '';

  const file = await fsPromises.readFile(oldPath);
  if (file instanceof Error) throw err;

  if (!file.toString().match(metadataRegex)) {
    let paths = { oldPath, newPath };
    return paths;
  }

  let metadata = file.toString().match(metadataRegex).toString();
  let category = metadata.match(categoryRegex);

  if (!category) {
    let paths = { oldPath, newPath };
    return paths;
  }

  category = category.toString().substring(3);
  newPath = join(pathToResources, category);
  let paths = { oldPath, newPath };
  return paths;
}

export function sortFiles(startPath) {
  readdir(startPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    let notes = markdownNotesOnly(files);
    notes.map(async (note) => {
      let paths = await getPaths(note);
      let { oldPath, newPath } = paths;
      rename(oldPath, join(newPath, note), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File moved successfully');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you try to put await on readFile() `await readFile` and try that way. Also just call getNewPaths and see if there is anything returned in `paths` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you posted is definitely incomplete since we can only give advice based on what we see here it goes my considerations:

1. You are creating a promisified function but you are using it with a callback. You should pick one style. The way the code is now your callback will never be called. You have to either use `fs.readFile` there or `readFile(oldPath).then(data =>`. Even better would be to use `fs.promises.readFile` if it is available on the Node.js version you are using
2. I can that the **paths** variable is indeed not defined on line inside the `sortFiles` function. The code is declaring that variable **inside** the function `getNewPath` making it unavailable inside the `sortFiles` function.
3. The variable `notes` is not defined either. The code is creating the `notes` variable inside the function `markdownNotesOnly`. Although sharing these values across function using the global scope is not encouraged if you choose to do that you should definitely declare it outside that function with `let notes`.
4. The **sortFiles** is not being called but since it is using an async function and you are not passing any callback to it as an argument it will pretty much work as a fire and forget kinda thing
5. The **sortFiles** function has the word sort in its name but it has a rename call in its body, that can be confusing even for yourself in the future.

But, the way to make your code stop throwing that very same error is by doing something like this:

```js
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
// const firstline = require('firstline')
// const moment = require('moment')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

const pathToResources =
  '/Users/Rob/Library/Mobile Documents/9CR7T2DMDG~com~ngocluu~onewriter/Documents/Test/Resources/'

let notes, paths
function markdownNotesOnly (files) {
  'use strict'
  return (notes = files.filter((file) => path.extname(file) === '.md'))
}

async function getNewPath (note) {
  const oldPath = path.join(__dirname, note)
  // let paths = {}
  let newPath = ''

  return readFile(oldPath).then(data => {
    const metadata = data
      .toString()
      .match(/-{3}\n.*\n-{3}/gms)
      .toString()
    let category = metadata.match(/#§-\d{3}-.*/)

    if (!category) {
      paths = { oldPath, newPath }
      return paths
    }

    category = category.toString().substring(3)
    newPath = path.join(pathToResources, category)
    paths = { oldPath, newPath }
    return paths
  })
}

function sortFiles (startPath) {
  fs.readdir(startPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err

    markdownNotesOnly(files) // returns array called notes

    notes.map(async (note) => {
      await getNewPath(note)

      const { oldPath, newPath } = paths

      fs.rename(oldPath, path.join(newPath, note), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('File moved successfully')
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks for this man, followed your advice and got it working this morning, you're an absolute legend